# O DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP também atualiza o campo no UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

Usando o `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` quando for feito um `UPDATE` essa data também sera atualizada para a data do `UPDATE`?

Ou ela e fixa inserida apenas uma única vez na hora do `INSERT`?

Comment: Depende como está sua tabela.

Answer (score 4):

Não, ele atualiza apenas na criação da linha.

Para atualizar tanto no insert quanto no update, são necessárias as duas declarações:

- `DEFAULT`
- `ON UPDATE`

Por exemplo:

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Mais detalhes no **[manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)**.

Agora, pode ocorrer de você não especificar nada na criação da tabela, e nesse caso o engine pode setar as duas condições por padrão na primeira coluna `timestamp`, por isso fica a sugestão de declarar explicitamente, para evitar comportamento inesperado.

Comment: +1 `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` pra campos de ultima atualização e `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` pra quando o registro foi criado :)